# iframe video autoplay=false

Tags: html, iframe, video

I have a video on my site and it continues to autoplay. The code currently reads:

```
<div class="cc-video-wrapper">
<iframe src="links/Clean-Energy-Overview-Wind Facts.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="500" autoplay="false" height="322" frameborder="0" 
lowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

So far, it continues to autoplay. I have tried autoplay="0", preload="false", autostart="false" and am running out of ideas. Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `video` tag:

```
<video width="500" height="322" controls>
    <source src="links/Clean-Energy-Overview-Wind Facts.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I have one other question: the background image of the video does not display on my mobile device (iphone 5), just the play button. The video plays fine (it appears once you press the play button) is there some kind of setting for this?

Comment: @Nikki_Heights is there any way we can do this without the video tag and using the iframe tag like in the question?